# Set python program to SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am running a python program on Raspberry Pi that I want to set to SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR priority.  I have found some info online of someone doing this in C/C++ with following code:

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=137341

How to do something like this in python either in code or in terminal assuming this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do something like this in python

The translation is fairly straightforward:

```
import os
param = os.sched_param(os.sched_get_priority_max(os.SCHED_FIFO))
os.sched_setscheduler(0, os.SCHED_FIFO, param)
```